# Drupal theme function for menu_block not being called

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7

I am using menu_block with D7. I read the readme (or: http://drupal.org/node/748022) but when I define a function `kw_menu_item_link__menu_block__6()` in my template.php, it is not being called.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Update: clearing the cache does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If it's a new template.php file, try [clearing the theme cache](http://drupal.org/node/337176), to force the theme system read the new file.</strike>

Update: Try using the [Theme Developer module](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) to double check that you have the function named correctly.

Comment: nope, the template.php existed before as well. And i cleared the cache often enough.